# Click automatically in specific points after recognition of text

Tags: python, click, mouse, s-function

I am using MATLAB and SIMULINK and there is something missing there that is driving me crazy, but **the question is not MATLAB-related.**

At a certain point I have a window like that:[image]

I would like to have the *SELECT ALL* button. I don't know why, but since a lot of years I am asking this feature to MathWorks but they don't implement it.

Anyway, I decided to do a workaround by myself.
I want to make a small script in Python which detect the text 'Tunable' and after it clicks automatically on ALL the checkboxes.

Is it possible to do it in Python ?

Comment: Have you looked into the python api? It might have the functionality to do it, and not require image recognition etc. - http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't look yet at it but I thought the best way to do something separated to launch when I need it.
But I don't know. I am open to know new opinons, I am really proficient in MATLAB/Simulink so if I would be able to implement this in MATLAB/Simulink it would be also better.

Comment: If it was me, I would explore every option before having to try and write a program that reads pixel data and does clicking (I think it would be a fair bit of work to implement). Looking at various apis may help you a lot. I don't know any matlab, but I do know that writing a program to look at the graphical output of another should be the very last option in your list.

Comment: So do you suggest to look into the APIs of matlab or what?

Comment: @minidiable  I suggest looking at undocumentedmatlab to figure out how to access the low-level java gui stuff that MATLAB has built its GUI on top of but tries to hide from you.  Generally speaking, if you want to do it, it is possible, but you have to bypass the MATLAB API to get it done.  Doing things that way is generally hard, painful, and buggy, but it can be done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure anymore it will be an easy task. I am looking at the undocumentedmatlab as you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

If you are interested you can look at it in this video:

[VIDEO YOUTUBE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJOnVMsGoF4)

I am happy to share ideas and to know your opinion.